# Equivalence in borel measures

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Hey guys so im asked to prove that $\mu$ a positive borel measure is regular and $\sigma-finite$ if and only if $\mu$ is locally finite.

I know that if a measure is positive and locally finite then its regular. But i have no idea how to get the other things done, any tips or advice would be great because i dont really have an idea on how to attack this problem, maybe contradiction i dont know.

Comment: What is the basic space on which your measure is defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mu$ be regular and sigma finite on $X$. There exists sets $A_n$ with $\mu(A_n) <\infty$ for all $n$ and  $X =\cup_n A_n$. By regularity there exist open sets $U_n$ such that $A_n \subset U_n$ and $\mu (U_n) <\infty$. If $K$ is any compact set then $K \subset \cup_n U_n$ so (by compactness)  there exists $N$ such that $K \subset \cup_{i=1}^{N} U_i$. It follows that $\mu (K) \leq \sum\limits_{i=1}^{N}\mu(U_i)<\infty$. Hence $\mu$ is locally finite.

The assertion that any locally finite measure is sigma finite is not true in general: let $X$ be the real line with discrete topology. Let $\mu(A)$ be the number of points in $A$ ($\infty$ if $A$ is an infinite set). Then $\mu$ is locally finite since only finite sets are compact. But $\mu$ is not sigma finite because the real line is uncountable.

Comment: Yeah , the fisrt part makes alot of sense , thanks !! Its not any locally finite measure , its a positive borel locally finite measure. I know that its going to be regular i just dont know how to do the $\sigma-finite$ part